# Exclude custom post_type in sitemap generation?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

I want to exclude some specific post types from generating sitemaps in yoast seo plugin. Please provide suggestions to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `functions.php` script to register custom post type, you should declare `false` to `'has_archive' => true,`.

```
function custom_post_type() {

  $labels = array( ... );
  $args = array(

    // you have to set it to False.
    'has_archive' => false,

  );
  register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked a long time ago, but the answer is kind of simple:

- Go to SEO --> Search Appearance.
- Select tab Contenttypes.
- Scroll down, here you can display or hide custom post types and archives from the sitemap.xml file.

Hope that helps for someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a filter solution:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 'your_prefix_exclude_cpt_from_sitemap', 10, 2 );

function your_prefix_exclude_cpt_from_sitemap( $value, $post_type ) {
    $post_types_to_exclude = [
        'post_type_one',
        'post_type_two'
    ];
    
    if ( in_array($post_type, $post_types_to_exclude) ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can use the "post_types_to_exclude" array to define multiple post types you want to exclude from the sitemap.